# Hidden Files in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

In Linux (specifically), what's the difference between making files hidden by adding a "." before the name, or adding a "~" after the name. I know that both work for files, and that only the period (to my knowledge) works for folders.

Whenever I search it, I always see tutorials that use the "." method, but whenever I see hidden files on my computer, they always use the "~" method, but those are always backup files.

I previously asked this on Stack Overflow, but they recommended I ask here instead. I hope this is the correct place.

Comment: Somewhat related: [history of `.files`](https://plus.google.com/+RobPikeTheHuman/posts/R58WgWwN9jp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matter of preference. `name~` tend to be temporary or backup files like the ones vim will create while editing files, and `.name` tend to be config files like .htaccess or .vimrc. All file managers hide `.name` but only *some* hide `name~`.

Comment: Great! Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. (I will accept the answer as soon as stack exchange lets me)